# Flutter: Building with plugins requires symlink support

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the below error in log whenever I try to install any dependency in `pubspec.yaml`

```
Building with plugins requires symlink support.

Please enable Developer Mode in your system settings. Run
  start ms-settings:developers
to open settings.
exit code 1
```

In `lib` folder, there is file named `generated_plugin_registrant.dart` which is also showing error, might be linked to above log error.

```
//
// Generated file. Do not edit.
//

// ignore_for_file: lines_longer_than_80_chars

import 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart';
import 'package:printing/src/printing_web.dart';

import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';

// ignore: public_member_api_docs
void registerPlugins(Registrar registrar) {
  FirebaseCoreWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  PrintingPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  registrar.registerMessageHandler();
}
```

Comment: but some people dont have administrator rights, what then?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

This worked for me:

on Windows 11 go to settings:
Click on **Privacy & Security** and after, click on **for developers** option.

On **for developers** settings, activate the **Developer mode** option (Install apps from any source...).

[image: Representation]

Now try to run/build your flutter application with **flutter run -d windows** or **flutter build windows** command.

Comment: and for non admins?

Comment: Yeah, what do non-admins do?

Comment: For Windows 10, click on Windows icon at bottom, click on the settings gear, search for 'developer settings', enable 'developer mode'

Comment: I do not feel comfortable enabling this setting. In 4 years I didn't see any project which has this requirement

Comment: For those who don't feel comfortable with always operating their machine in developer mode, you only have to enable the mode and run the flutter app once to create the link.  You can then disable the developer mode and your application will still build an run.

Comment: Okay cool, Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 55):

Hey I was having the same problem I just activate the development settings and run again it works for me use the command :

```
 start ms-settings:developers
```

Comment: There are several settings in that window, none of which mention symlink. Which is the correct setting?

Comment: I was also confused by the message and looked up for some symlink-enabling setting, it actually means to enable "Developer mode" (the topmost setting that mentions allowing the installation of apps from any source)

Answer (score 23):

Installation of some plugins required special allowance.
This requires permission for windows which is available in **For Developer**.
It is much like **Install from unknown source** type permission.

**How to allow permission:**

Search **Developer Settings** in the start menu and open it. Under **developer mode** click on **Install apps from any source, including loose file**.
Run pub-get again and you are good to go.

Answer (score 10):

First, run the command line interface with run administrator
and then run this command

start ms-settings:developers

pop will come with privacy setting just enable developer mode it.[image]

Comment: is there aworkaround for those who dont have admin accesss

Comment: really helpful !

Answer (score 7):

If you feel uncomfortable turning on Developer Mode to allow side loaded apps and you aren't targeting Windows OS, you can avoid doing `flutter pub add package_name`. Instead, clear out the old package with `dart pub remove package_name` manually edit your `pubspec.yaml` with the dependency and do a `flutter pub get`.

Comment: I only experience this issue when running flutter command in VSCode which usually not showing this error, but if I used Powershell with admin privilege, no issue so far

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure, how relevant is my answer. I got the same error, but the problem is as follows.

I accidentally change the device to 'Windows machine' instead of my mobile in  VS Code.
If you really want to run apps on Windows platform, you can choose other options.

Answer (score 6):

Go to **Windows settings**. Select **Update & Security**. On that, select **For Developers**. In that window, there is an option called **Install apps from any source, including loose files** on the *Developer Mode*. ***Enable that option***.

Answer (score 5):

This happens when you are running on flutter 3.0 and above;
The error only occurs when your selected device is Windows OS.
If your are not developing a windows application, you can just change your selected device to your android emulator or your physical mobile phone.

If you are developing a windows application then you need to turn ON developers option on your windows device to allow debugging.

Comment: I get this message on windows trying to run on chrome

Answer (score 5):

directly go to search of window and search

> **developer settings**

and you will see the

> **developer mode** and make it `yes`.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 10 Go to cmd add this command > start ms-settings:developers
it will appear Settings Window
allow developer mode [Allow developer mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQvHg.png)

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings, click Update and Security, click For Developers ->Developer Mode -> Enable Install apps from any source, including loose files.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Run `start ms-settings:developers` and turn on developer option

Answer (score 1):

Heres a command that should work in powershell with admin rights

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "1"
```

And to turn developer mode off

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

adding dependency above dev_dependencies worked for me

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```