# flutter, dart : Building with plugins requires symlink support. Please enable Developer Mode in your system settings.Run start ms-settings:developers

Tags: flutter, dart

i am adding **image piker** Package in **pubspec.yaml** when i run **flutter pub get** so the following out put is shown
package version **image_picker: ^0.8.5+3**

```
Building with plugins requires symlink support.

Please enable Developer Mode in your system settings. Run
  start ms-settings:developers
to open settings.
exit code 1
```

so what is should do to add **image_picker** properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it is in windows 10 and above, you must enable developer mode, will fix your problem.

open cmd and run

```
start ms-settings:developers
```

a window will open, then enable developer mode to on.
[image]

read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68089177/flutter-building-with-plugins-requires-symlink-support?rq=1)

Comment: and for those who dont have admni access?

Comment: if your windows ask for administrator privileges or an admin password, you must provide it.